# Is "чалый" a synonym of "рецидивист"?

Tags: словоупотребление, semantics

Several websites I've come across state "чалый" as a synonym of "рецидивист", but I haven't been able to find any definitions of чалый that would suggest it's synonymous with рецидивист.

Are they synonymous? Is one a slang word for another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Чалиться* is a slang word meaning, in the wider sense, "be stuck somewhere, be forced to waste time": *чалиться на заводе, чалиться в деревне* etc.

In the narrower sense, *чалиться* means "to do one's time" (as in the prison). This might be used as *чалиться на шконке* ("do the time on the prison bunk bed") or *чалиться на зоне* ("do one's time in the corrective colony") or similar.

The person who is known to have been engaged in this activity might be called *чалый*.

This is an active participle from this verb, using an old pattern with *-л-* which is not productive in Russian anymore.

Comment: _Passive_ participle?.. Anyhow, the verb _чалиться_ comes from _чалить_ (derivative: _причалить_) "to haul, tug, and then attach a boat to the pier." In the slang of _бурлаки_ (barge haulers), the verb _чалиться_ meant "to pull barge with rope". In its figurative meaning "pull the strap, to do the long and exhausting ordeal = to be in prison" it migrated into the criminal slang.

Comment: @YellowSky: yes, passive participle (*страдательное причастие*), why? The pattern with *-л-* is not productive anymore and those are perceived more like adjectives these days (*зрелый, вялый, бывалый, лежалый* etc.). Normally they are actually called "deverbal adjectives". But in this very case we see the formation of a new word so I thought participle would be a better word to describe it.

Comment: My point is that in Russian one cannot form a _passive_ participle (страдательное причастие) from an _intransitive_ verb.

Comment: @YellowSky: do we consider *зрелый* and *лежалый* participles (at least from etymological perspective)? *Зреть* and *лежать* are both intransitive.

Comment: Sure, they are participles, but note, they are past **active** participles. Active, not passive. "Чалый" is 'тот, кто чалил', not 'тот, кого чалили', "зрелый" — 'тот, который созрел', not 'тот, которого созрели'. Active, not passive.

Comment: @YellowSky: oh yes, you're totally right, brain fault on my part!